# How do I convert a list of strings to variables in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, variables

For example, if I have S=['a','b','c'], I want to have 3 variables a_value=0, b_value=0, c_value=0. Maybe I am approaching it a wrong way, but at the moment that is what I am trying to do!

Comment: a_value, b_value, c_value = ['a', 'b', 'c']?

Comment: Yes, dynamic variable names is always approaching it the wrong way. Maybe looking for a dict, `values = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}` where you can access `values[x]`.

Answer (score 2):

Python allows you to dynamically create global (not local) variables by setting them in the dictionary returned by the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function. Using your list would look like this:

```py
S = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for v in S:
    globals()[f'{v}_value'] = 0

print(a_value)
print(b_value)
print(c_value)
```

which prints

```
0
0
0
```

as expected. Note that the scope of a "global variable" in Python is the module in which the `globals()` function is called - this may be different than what you would expect coming from other languages.

As mentioned in comments, there is almost always a better approach that leads to nicer code that is easier to debug.

Comment: The section of the docs that you linked says:  *Note:The contents of this dictionary should not be modified*.

Comment: @wim, thanks - updated to use `globals()`.

Answer (score -2):

You can assign the list items with commas

```
S=['a','b','c']
S[0], S[1], S[2] = 0,0,0
print(S)
>>>
[0, 0, 0]
```